# How can I get the number of selected files in $request->file('file') postman laravel

Tags: laravel, postman

I want to upload one or more files at the same time in postman. I would like to create a condition to check if the number of uploaded files is equal to 1 write some code else write another code. I would like to be able to count the file number. Any idea how to do that please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCpEt.png)

Answer (score 1):

In laravel try something like this:

```
  if (is_array($request->file('file')) and count($request->file('file')) != 1) {
     // uploaded files is not equal to 1 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be done in the validation

```php
'file' => ['min:1', 'max:1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to make sure at least one file is uploaded along with other validation rules

```
'file' => ['min:1', ....]
```

Then check the number of files uploaded and add your code accordingly.

```
 if (count($request->file('file')) == 1) {
     // code for a single file 
 } elseif (count($request->file('file)) > 1) {
     // code for multiple files
 }
```